# Scraping a website that uses AJAX Post to populate the data

Tags: python, html, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was wondering if it was at all possible using `beautifulsoup` to scrape a website that loads a table based on an ajax call.

Below is the python code I am using to access the div that contains the table

`table = bs.find(lambda tag: tag.name=='div' and tag.has_key('id') and tag['id']=="id+name")`

When that is executed I get an empty div `<div id="id+name"></div>`

The java script/ajax function looks like this

```
function getTable(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<some processing file .asmx>",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(msg){
            $('#table+id').html(msg.d);
        }
    });
```

I think I'm getting blank because it is trying to scrape the table before the page is processed. Is this something that can be handled in beautiful soup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BeautifulSoup` is just an HTML parser. You need something to execute that javascript call and/or make that `POST` request.

Basically, you have two options:

- use a tool that utilizes a real browser, like [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/). This way you make the browser do all the work for loading the page and executing javascript for you. You can use [`find_element_by_id()`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element_by_id) to get to the element.
- make that `POST` request using [`urllib2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html) or [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and parse the results. According to the javascript code you've provided - the response is in `JSON` format and it contains an `HTML` code for the table inside:

  ```
  import json

  from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
  import requests

  URL = "<some processing file .asmx>"
  response = requests.post(URL)
  data = json.loads(response.content)

  div = BeautifulSoup(data['d'])
  ```

UPD (the actual working code that gets the table):

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

import requests


URL = 'http://www.ise.com/MarketDataService.asmx/ISE_Get_IntraDay_Summary'
response = requests.post(URL, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'})
data = json.loads(response.content)

soup = BeautifulSoup(data['d'])
for row in soup('tr'):
    print " | ".join(cell.text for cell in row('td'))
```

Prints:

```
All Securities  | All Equities Only | All Indices & ETF Only
16:15 | 244,754 | 258,519 | 503,273 | 95 | 192,025 | 85,778 | 277,803 | 224 | 52,726 | 172,741 | 225,467 | 31
16:10 | 244,473 | 260,881 | 505,354 | 94 | 192,025 | 85,778 | 277,803 | 224 | 52,445 | 175,103 | 227,548 | 30
15:50 | 232,697 | 227,149 | 459,846 | 102 | 182,351 | 81,672 | 264,023 | 223 | 50,343 | 145,477 | 195,820 | 35 
...
```

Comment: Do you have any recommendations?

Comment: @Alex sure, give me a second, made the point but I'm improving the answer. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I think I am going to go with option 2, however the processing file is a relative path. When I combine that relative path with the one that is in the browser (there is no upwards movement) I get a non-existent page. Also tried it in python and that came back as no JSON object

Comment: Also when I use the full url (site + processing file) I get a return of 200 which I'm assuming means its there but just wont return anything *update - found that i was getting the 200 because they have a page setup as a 404 redirect

Comment: @Alex okay, can you provide a link, so I can reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thats excellent... would you mind explaining how you knew to shorten the url and remove the `/market-data/isee-index/` portion? Just so I know in the future the theory

Comment: @Alex I've just inspected the request/response in the network tab inside chrome developer tools. Then, just simulated it in the code.